# У нее была мечта (:) в обители иметь святыню – икону преподобной

Tags: пунктуация, определения, двоеточие, уточнения

**У нее была мечта: в обители иметь святыню – икону преподобной.**

- Поставила двоеточие. Опиралась на принцип избежания двух тире, о котором в некоторых правилах говорится:
- > Встречается постановка двоеточия при пояснительном члене предложения. Обычно двоеточие ставится для того, чтобы избежать двух тире. *Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений – водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.*
- > Изредка в бессоюзном сложном предложении, состоящем из трех частей, встречается постановка двух двоеточий (на разных основаниях или с одним и тем же основанием)... Обычно в таких предложениях, чтобы избежать скопления двоеточий, одно из них заменяют тире.
- Можно ли так делать в данном случае: в случае с обособленным определением (*в обители иметь святыню*) и уточнением (*икону преподобной*)? Можно ли считать *в обители иметь святыню* пояснительным членом предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок слов в вашем предложении странный. Возможно, он оправдан контекстом, но, исходя из того, что у нас есть, желательно его изменить так, как предложила Jasmin. Двоеточие в таком случае опционально, по-моему.

> У тебя же была розовая **мечта ― иметь** настоящий «Паркер», но из-за ден>ег жаба душила. [Андрей Житков. Супермаркет (2000)]
>
> У ней есть **мечта иметь** свою корову; что ж, если дела пойдут, как шли, это можно будет сделать через год. [Н. Г. Чернышевский. Что делать? (1863)]

И все-таки я бы предпочел поставить двоеточие:

**У нее была мечта: иметь в обители святыню — икону преподобной.**

Answer (score 2):

Вариант редактирования:

**У нее была мечта (какая?) иметь в обители святыню – икону преподобной.**

В предложенном варианте два оборота со значением пояснения, а это сложно как для оформления, так и для прочтения и понимания предложения.

Поэтому определительный оборот на основе инфинитива лучше не обособлять.

Comment: _Мечта иметь в обители святыню была несбыточной_. Чувствуете разницу? Вот здесь обособление не нужно, более того – ошибочно. А во фразе автора – необходимо. Не вводите в заблуждение, открывайте почаще справочник.